# How can I define a constant vector layer in Caffe?

Tags: caffe

I have a data with 10-d label vector, and I want to use a caffe model to make regression against these data with 10-d output. But now, I only want to check loss of some outputs (for example, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6-d of 10-d vector), so I define a layer with 5-d output at the bottom of the last output layer, But I'v no idea how to get corresponding 5-d label vector groundtruth, I think  may be I can define a constant layer to indicate which entries I want get. Please help me if you have any ideas.

**update: example**

This is my original InnerProduct and Loss layer

```
layer {
   name: "score"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   bottom: "fc7"
   top: "score"
   inner_product_param {
      num_output: 10
      weight_filler {
         type: "gaussian"
         std: 0.005
      }
      bias_filler {
         type: "constant"
         value: 1
      }
   }
}

layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "score"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}
```

I  care more about $n_1$ (like 1,3,4,5,6) entries of the 10-dimension output and their loss, so I want to fetch the loss of these entries, like

```
layer {
   name: "score1"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   bottom: "fc7"
   top: "score1"
   inner_product_param {
      num_output: 5                  # n_1
      weight_filler {
         type: "gaussian"
         std: 0.005
      }
      bias_filler {
         type: "constant"
         value: 1
      }
   }
}

layer {
  name: "loss1"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "score1"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss1"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}
```

How can I get score1 from score directly?

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to do. can you please add an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I interpret from your question, I think you would like to calculate the loss of the output layer w.r.t the labels for a regression model. But you would like to not bring some of the labels to the equation.

If my interpretation is true, being a regression model, I am expecting your new layer to be something similar to that of EuclidieanLayer. If it is so, the `caffe_sub` function in the layer could be replaced by the following code segment.

```
  int arrayPos[5] = {1,3,4,5,6};
  int count = 5;
  Dtype *newBottom0=(Dtype*)malloc(sizeof(Dtype)*count);
  Dtype *newBottom1=(Dtype*)malloc(sizeof(Dtype)*count);
  for(int varI=0; varI<count; varI++)
  {
    newBottom0[varI] = (Dtype) bottom[0]->cpu_data()[arrayPos[varI]];
    newBottom1[varI] = (Dtype) bottom[1]->cpu_data()[arrayPos[varI]];
  }
  caffe_sub( count, newBottom0, newBottom1, diff_.mutable_cpu_data());
  free(newBottom0);
  free(newBottom1);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I mean. Can I just add a layer something like [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,] to get entries {1,3,4,5,6} without modifying caffe files?

Comment: Being a regression model, having such a ground truth wont be useful, if that is what you mean.

Comment: That's not the groudtruth, it just indicates wihich entries in 10-dimension output I care about

Comment: If the labels keep changing for each image, then adding a extra blob to the new layer would make sense, else the above mentioned code segment itself will solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your help, I'll give it try.

Comment: Upvote if you find it useful and accept this as the answer if it could solve your problem. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108369/discussion-between-fungtion-and-anoop-k-prabhu).